# will_paginate giving an error when doing a search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Alrighty, so I have searched on here repeatedly on this as well as other places but have yet to find the solution that relates to me. Probably because the previous questions were some time ago.

My problem is that I had first added pagination and then I was required to add a search so that users could search for products. When they do the search it's just supposed to open the products page. If I took out the search, the pagination doesn't give me an error.

The error I get now is

> ''undefined method `total_pages' for # Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:''

and the line of code highlighted for the error is the pagination in the `index.html.erb`.

What am I missing? Thanks for any guidance, this newbie needs it!

This is the products_controller:

```
  def index
   if Rails.env == "development"
    name_env = "name LIKE ?"
   else
    name_env = "name ilike ?"
   end
   if params[:q]
    search_term = params[:q]
    @products = Product.search(search_term)
   else
    @products = Product.all
    @products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 4)
   end
  end
```

This is the index.html.erb :

```
  <div class="pagination">
   <%= will_paginate @products %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify index action as follows:

```
def index
    if Rails.env == "development"
        name_env = "name LIKE ?"
    else
        name_env = "name ilike ?"
    end
    @products = params[:q] ? Product.search(params[:q]) : Product.scoped
    @products.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 4)
end
```

you should use `paginate` for searching too.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh :) , what do you mean  “use paginate on searching”?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `paginate` method when the search, it `@products = Product.search(search_term)` will be like this

```
.....
if params[:q]
    search_term = params[:q]
    @products = Product.search(search_term).paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 4)
else
    @products = Product.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 4)
.....
```

**Additionally** Remove this `@products = Product.all` don't need this.

After all, you just paste this instead of your code, it reduced

```
def index
   if Rails.env == "development"
    name_env = "name LIKE ?"
   else
    name_env = "name ilike ?"
   end
   if params[:q]
    search_term = params[:q]
    @products = Product.search(search_term)
   else
    @products = Product.all
   end
   @products = @products.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 4)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! As soon as I can I will try those changes :)